# Why does my mouse not work in Counter Strike Global Offense?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CS Go having problem playing with friends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86704/cs-go-having-problem-playing-with-friends)

In Counter Strike Global Offense when I start a private match and invite a friend I can´t move my view with the mouse, the cursor is shown on top of all and i may only walk and jump, but not shoot or look around. My friend apperantly has the same problem.
How may I fix this and what´s the cause of it?

Comment: Are you both using the same type of mouse? Have you tried swapping out your mouse for another one?

Comment: Is this for the PC or ps3?

Comment: We are not using the same mouse and we are not using even nearly equal hardware, it´s for pc and another friend told me about the same problem... My first friend has a highend gamer pc approx 3 months old, I have an middleclass computer and my other friend uses his notebook my first friend and i are using win 7 ultimate and my other friend win xp professional

Comment: So the reason has to be ingame, i already tried debug mode but i see no informations about it

Comment: Do you have any type of "always on top" software or music running in an application in the background?

Comment: I use Winamp but my friends don´t. And even if i close my winamp the same problem occures. The only other "on top" software which is running on all three computers is the steam game overlay but certainly this isn´t the cause.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86704/cs-go-having-problem-playing-with-friends/87305

Comment: This is an extremely common problem. I get it occasionally and just restart. It is likely related to the server you're trying to connect to, so perhaps try a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, In this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86704/cs-go-having-problem-playing-with-friends/87305) there is an proper answer and I´m afraid that there currently is no solution...